# Mockito gives UnfinishedVerificationException when it seems OK

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, junit5

Mockito appears to be throwing an `UnfinishedVerificationException` when I think I've done everything correctly. Here's my partial test case:

```
HttpServletRequest req = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
when(req.getHeader("Authorization")).thenReturn("foo");

HttpServletResponse res = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);

classUnderTest.doMethod(req, res); // Use the mock

verify(res, never());
verify(req).setAttribute(anyString(), anyObject());
```

And here's the partial class and method:

```
class ClassUnderTest extends AnotherClass {
    @Override
    public String doMethod(ServletRequest req, ServletRequest res) {
        // etc.
        return "someString";
    }
}
```

Ignoring the fact that you should never mock interfaces you don't own, why is Mockito giving me the following message?

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at (redacted)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.

at [test method name and class redacted]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
... etc
```

Comment: How does the class of the `classUnderTest` look like? What's the method's signature? It works fine for me with public non-final classes/methods.

Comment: I've updated the question with the ClassUnderTest

Comment: Is the line referred to in the message (which you've redacted) the same as the line where the exception is actually thrown?  Usually, if you have unfinished verification, Mockito won't report it until the NEXT time you use a Mockito method.  It may well be that your problem is in the test method immediately BEFORE this one.  That's why Mockito reports the line number where the error occurs SEPARATELY from the stack trace itself.

Comment: Thank-you, David. That was the problem. Would you copy your comment to an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

I just came across this my self and it caused me a lot of confusion.

As David mentioned above Mockito reports errors in the **next** Mockito method call which may not be in the same test method. While the exception message does contain a reference to the actual place the error occurred I find having incorrect tests failing counter productive to the testing process. And the simpler the tests the more likely an error is to show up in the next test!

Here is an easy fix that will ensure errors appear in the correct test method:

```java
@After
public void validate() {
    validateMockitoUsage();
}
```

From the Mockito documentation [here](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.25.1/org/mockito/Mockito.html#validateMockitoUsage--):

> Mockito throws exceptions if you misuse it so that you know if your
>   tests are written correctly. **The gotcha is that Mockito does the
>   validation next time you use the framework** (e.g. next time you verify,
>   stub, call mock etc.). But even though the exception might be thrown
>   in the next test, the exception message contains a navigable stack
>   trace element with location of the defect. Hence you can click and
>   find the place where Mockito was misused.
>
> Sometimes though, you might
>   want to validate the framework usage explicitly. For example, one of
>   the users wanted to put validateMockitoUsage() in his @After method so
>   that he knows immediately when he misused Mockito. Without it, he
>   would have known about it not sooner than next time he used the
>   framework. **One more benefit of having validateMockitoUsage() in @After
>   is that jUnit runner will always fail in the test method with defect**
>   whereas ordinary 'next-time' validation might fail the next test
>   method. But even though JUnit might report next test as red, don't
>   worry about it and just click at navigable stack trace element in the
>   exception message to instantly locate the place where you misused
>   mockito.

Comment: See MockitoRule class here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40793464/parameterized-testing-with-mockito-by-using-junit-rule

Answer (score 119):

This might also be caused if you try to `verify` a method which expects primitive arguments with `any()`:

For example, if our method has this signature:

```
method(long l, String s);
```

And you try to verify it like this, it will fail with aforementioned message:

```
verify(service).method(any(), anyString());
```

Change it to `anyLong()` and it will work:

```
verify(service).method(anyLong(), anyString());
```

Comment: Why not pass **anyString()**?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Thanks, changed to anyString()

Comment: Voted up because this is what happened to me. The error message doesn't mention that any() can't match primitives.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. The error message is really misguided.

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem. You doesn't have to use `anyString()` for String data type.

Comment: This solved my problem. I was keep getting `NullPointerException`. Sometimes message is misleading. In my case argument was `int` type and passing `any()`. By changing it to `anyInt()` fixed the issue.

Comment: Exactly the problem. Unbelievable!

Comment: thanks. Mockito verify() gets me everytime with the confusing any() function. They should have had more explicit name.. any() sounds like it would allow anything.

Answer (score 14):

I was getting this same error due to using `any()` with a `boolean` parameter, when apparently it needed to be `anyBoolean()`.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, using **kotlin** was because the funcion to test was not declared as `open`.

The exception notices that no `final`/private/equals/hash methods can be used.

```
fun increment(){
        i++
    }
```

to

```
open fun increment(){
        i++
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

With Junit 5, you can add the following to show more meaningful Mockito exceptions in the console

```
@AfterEach
public void validate() {
    validateMockitoUsage()
}
```

Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22550055/8073652

Answer (score 3):

I had similar exception with class MyRepository

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
>   Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
>   -> at MyRepository$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$de8d8358.invoke()
>
> Example of correct verification:
>
> ```
> verify(mock).doSomething()
> ```

The problem was resolved when I created interface for MyRepository, and mock interface, but not implementation.
It seems spring creates some CGLIB proxies and it leads to UnfinishedVerificationException exception.

Answer (score 3):

For me the issue turned out to be a missing bean declaration in the test context xml. It was for a custom aspect class used by another class, an instance of which is a parameter to the constructor of the class which is the parameter to failing verify() call. So I added the bean declaration to the context xml and it worked fine after that.

Answer (score 2):

Two answers above suggested using `validateMockitoUsage()` method after each test.

While this is correct I found that annotating your class with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)` 
in Junit 5 give the same effect while adding some the nice Mockito functionalities. Also, it looks cleaner to me as well.

I guess Junit 4 `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` will give a similar result but I didn't test it.

Answer (score 2):

Changed to `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and the issue went away. 
Was using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` earlier.

Hope that helps someone..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, too, on the following stack:

- Kotlin
- Junit `4.13`
- Mockito `2.28.2` + Mockito-Inline `2.13.0`
- Robolectric `4.3.1`

I tried to verify a lambda call:

```kotlin
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MainViewTest {

    @get:Rule
    val mockitoRule: MockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule()

    @Mock private lateinit var mockClickCallback: () -> Unit

    @Test
    fun `should call clickCallback on the button click`() {
        val activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity::class.java).create().get()
        val viewUnderTest = MainView(activity)
        viewUnderTest.setClickCallback(mockClickCallback)

        viewUnderTest.button.performClick()

        verify(mockClickCallback).invoke() // UnfinishedVerificationException
    }
}
```

Then I found [the issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/5076) on Github, it seems that the problem is in Robolectric. I used the following workaround:

```kotlin
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class MainViewTest {

    private interface UnitFunction: () -> Unit

    @Test
    fun `should call clickCallback on the button click`() {
        val activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity::class.java).create().get()
        val viewUnderTest = MainView(activity)
        val mockClickCallback = mock(UnitFunction::class.java) as () -> Unit
        viewUnderTest.setClickCallback(mockClickCallback)

        viewUnderTest.button.performClick()

        verify(mockClickCallback).invoke() // OK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, i found a way to solve this. Mock objects which you for verify haven't been reseted, so you should reset it .You can **reset(mock)** before your test case function, it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to verify a private or package-private method with Mockito.verify you will get this error.

If you don't want to use PowerMockito you can set your method as protected and I advise you to add the @VisibleForTesting tag:

Before:

```
void doSomething() {
   //Some behaviour
}
```

After :

```
@VisibleForTesting
protected void doSomething() {
   //Some behaviour
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-at com.xxx.MyTest.testRun_Should_xxx_When_yyy(MyTest.java:127)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Also, this error might show up because you verify either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.


    at com.xxx.MyTest.validate(MyTest.java:132)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runAfters(MethodRoadie.java:145)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:99)
...
```

In my case, the error was generated because I was using a *PowerMockito.verifyStatic()* before my *Mockito.verify(...)* call, then I had to move the *PowerMockito.verifyStatic()* to last line (or delete it).

From:

```
PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
Mockito.verify(myMock, Mockito.times(1)).myMockedMethod(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), any(XXX.class), any(YYY.class), any(ZZZ.class));
```

To:

```
Mockito.verify(myMock, Mockito.times(1)).myMockedMethod(anyString(), anyString(), anyString(), any(XXX.class), any(YYY.class), any(ZZZ.class)); 
PowerMockito.verifyStatic();
```

Answer (score 0):

The tests run individually well but while running integration test suite it fails with the UnfinishedVerificationException. The issue arises when we use verify() from mockito and have @EnableRetry.
Workaround for this is to use

```
public static <T> T unwrapAndVerify(T mock, VerificationMode mode) {
   return ((T) Mockito.verify(AopTestUtils.getTargetObject(mock), mode));
}
```

as mentioned in [Mocked Spring @Service that has @Retryable annotations on methods fails with UnfinishedVerificationException](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39341119/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my grain of salt!
I discovered there is a conflict between **Mockito** and **Hibernate Validation**.
My solution is the separate my contract checks (@NotNull, @NotEmpty, etc) from the mockito tests. I also started using `validateMockitoUsage()` to ensure everything was run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

(**In case you can also completely ignore all error hints like me**)
In my case it was a misuse of the API. Code looked like this:

```
verify(mockedInstance.concreteMethod(), times(x));
```

Instead of (as docs clearly says)

```
verify(mockedInstance, times(x)).concreteMethod();
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure where are your "classUnderTest" come from, but please keep sure it's **mocked**, **not a real one**.
I have the same issue for my test case below:

```
MyAgent rpc = new MyAgent("myNodeName");
...
rpc.doSomething();
...
PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(rpc).invoke("initPowerSwitch");
PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(rpc).invoke("init", "192.168.0.23", "b2", 3);
```

But it's disappeared for the following test case:

```
MyAgent rpc = PowerMockito.spy(new MyAgent("myNodeName"));
...
rpc.doSomething();
...
PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(rpc).invoke("initPowerSwitch");
PowerMockito.verifyPrivate(rpc).invoke("init", "192.168.0.23", "b2", 3);
```

Attention, the Object rpc should be mocked by **PowerMockito.spy(...)**.

Answer (score -1):

Faced same exception when used mockStatic method and called Mockito.verify multiple times, but passed interface instead of implementing class.

wrong code:

```
try (MockedStatic<Service> staticMock = Mockito.mockStatic(Service.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)) {
  staticMock.verify(() -> ServiceImpl.method()); // passed without errors
  staticMock.verify(() -> ServiceImpl.method()); // throws UnfinishedVerificationException 
}
```

fixed code:

```
try (MockedStatic<ServiceImpl> staticMock = Mockito.mockStatic(Service.class, Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)) {
  staticMock.verify(() -> ServiceImpl.method());
  staticMock.verify(() -> ServiceImpl.method());
}
```

It was my mistake obviosly, but UnfinishedVerificationException message was not helpfull