# Mocked Spring @Service that has @Retryable annotations on methods fails with UnfinishedVerificationException

Tags: spring, mockito, spring-batch, spring-aop, spring-retry

I'm using Spring Boot `1.4.0.RELEASE` with `spring-boot-starter-batch`, `spring-boot-starter-aop` and `spring-retry`

I have a Spring Integration test that has a `@Service` which is mocked at runtime.  I've noticed that if the `@Service` class contains any `@Retryable` annotations on its methods, then it appears to interfere with `Mockito.verify()`, I get a `UnfinishedVerificationException`.  I presume this must be something to do with `spring-aop`?  If I comment out all `@Retryable` annotations in the `@Service` then verify works ok again.

I have created a [github project](https://github.com/pearj/spring-boot-batch-retry-issue) that demonstrates this issue.

It fails in `sample.batch.MockBatchTestWithRetryVerificationFailures.batchTest()` at `validateMockitoUsage();`

With something like:

```
12:05:36.554 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDirtiesContextTestExecutionListener - After test method: context [DefaultTestContext@5ec0a365 testClass = MockBatchTestWithRetryVerificationFailures, testInstance = sample.batch.MockBatchTestWithRetryVerificationFailures@5abca1e0, testMethod = batchTest@MockBatchTestWithRetryVerificationFailures, testException = org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at sample.batch.service.MyRetryService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7573ce2a.invoke(<generated>)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()
```

However I have another class (`sample.batch.MockBatchTestWithNoRetryWorking.batchTest()`) with a mocked `@Service` that doesn't have any `@Retryable` annotation and verify works fine.

What am I doing wrong?

In my pom.xml I have the following:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
...
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
    </dependency>
...
```

Then all the related Java Classes

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class SampleBatchApplication {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Autowired
    private MyRetryService myRetryService;

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceNoRetry myServiceNoRetry;

    @Bean
    protected Tasklet tasklet() {

        return new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
                    ChunkContext context) {
                myServiceNoRetry.process();
                myRetryService.process();
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
        };

    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() throws Exception {
        return this.jobs.get("job").start(step1()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step step1() throws Exception {
        return this.steps.get("step1").tasklet(tasklet()).build();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // System.exit is common for Batch applications since the exit code can be used to
        // drive a workflow
        System.exit(SpringApplication
                .exit(SpringApplication.run(SampleBatchApplication.class, args)));
    }

    @Bean
    ResourcelessTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new ResourcelessTransactionManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRepository getJobRepo() throws Exception {
        return new MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean(transactionManager()).getObject();
    }

}

@Service
public class MyRetryService {

    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRetryService.class);

    @Retryable(maxAttempts = 5, include = RuntimeException.class, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 100, multiplier = 2))
    public boolean process() {

        double random = Math.random();

        LOG.info("Running process, random value {}", random);

        if (random > 0.2d) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Random fail time!");
        }

        return true;
    }

}

@Service
public class MyServiceNoRetry {

    public static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceNoRetry.class);

    public boolean process() {

        LOG.info("Running process that doesn't do retry");

        return true;
    }

}

@ActiveProfiles("Test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SampleBatchApplication.class, MockBatchTestWithNoRetryWorking.MockedRetryService.class}, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MockBatchTestWithNoRetryWorking {

    @Autowired
    MyServiceNoRetry service;

    @Test
    public void batchTest() {
        service.process();

        verify(service).process();
        validateMockitoUsage();
    }

    public static class MockedRetryService {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public MyServiceNoRetry myService() {
            return mock(MyServiceNoRetry.class);
        }
    }
}

@ActiveProfiles("Test")
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { SampleBatchApplication.class,
        MockBatchTestWithRetryVerificationFailures.MockedRetryService.class },
                      loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MockBatchTestWithRetryVerificationFailures {

    @Autowired
    MyRetryService service;

    @Test
    public void batchTest() {
        service.process();

        verify(service).process();
        validateMockitoUsage();
    }

    public static class MockedRetryService {
        @Bean
        @Primary
        public MyRetryService myRetryService() {
            return mock(MyRetryService.class);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Updated question and code based on a sample project I put together to show the problem.

Comment: can you update you code

Comment: @kuhajeyan sure, I've done that now.  Hopefully, I've included enough information

Comment: @kuhajeyan updated again, but with working example in github that you can try

Comment: thx will check this

Answer (score 5):

So after looking at a similar [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5837) for `spring-boot`

I found that there is an extra proxy getting in the way.  I found a nasty hack by unwrapping the aop class by hand, makes verification work, ie:

```
@Test
public void batchTest() throws Exception {
    service.process();

    if (service instanceof Advised) {
        service = (MyRetryService) ((Advised) service).getTargetSource().getTarget();
    }

    verify(service).process();
    validateMockitoUsage();
}
```

Hopefully, this can be fixed similar to the above github issue. I'll raise an issue and see how far I get.

EDIT: Raised the [github issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6828)

Comment: I Opened one for `WebServiceGatewaySupport ` as well. seems not solved. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11920

Comment: this is what is cleanest of all

Answer (score 3):

After I've seen [@Joel Pearsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/359999/joel-pearson) answer, and especially the linked GitHub issue, I worked around this by temporarily using a static helper method that unwraps and verifies:

```
public static <T> T unwrapAndVerify(T mock, VerificationMode mode) {
    return ((T) Mockito.verify(AopTestUtils.getTargetObject(mock), mode));
}
```

With this method the only difference in the test cases is the verification call. There is no overhead other than this:

```
unwrapAndVerify(service, times(2)).process();
```

instead of

```
verify(service, times(2)).process();
```

Actually, it was even possible to name the helper method like the actual Mockito method, so that you only need to replace the import, but I didn't like the subsequent confusion.

However, unwrapping shouldn't be required if `@MockBean` is used instead of `mock()` to create the mocked bean. Spring Boot 1.4 supports this annotation.

Comment: very weird, because in the github issue they never explain why the problem is gone when we use @MockBean.