# Unit test with mocks work in IntelliJ, fail with Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, junit, mockito

I have some Unittests for my Project and they work if i run them with IntelliJ.
However if i run them with Maven alot of them fail.
I am using SpringBoot.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = MainApplication.class)    
public class ServiceTest {
private static boolean mockInitialized = false;

@Autowired
private IService Service;

@MockBean
private IDAO DAO;

@MockBean
private ISearchDAO SearchDAO;


@Before
public void setUp() {
    if (!mockInitialized) {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        mockInitialized = true;
    }
} 
@Test
public void getByIdPersists() throws Exception {

    DTO dto = new DTO(1, "test");
    when(DAO.getById(1)).thenReturn(dto);
    DTO found = Service.getById(1);

    verify(DAO).getById(1);

    assertEquals(dto, found);
}
```

The executed DAO is not the same es the one to verify in Maven while it is in IntelliJ
The Errormessage for this:

[ERROR] getByIdPersists(ServiceTest)  Time elapsed: 0 s  <<< ERROR!
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException:

Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at ServiceTest.getByIdPersists(ServiceTest.java:130)

Example of correct verification:
    verify(mock).doSomething()

Comment: Error Message??

Comment: Off topic: Your setup method looks like you might want to read up on `@BeforeClass`.

Comment: works for me, please provide us with exception being thrown

Comment: You shouldn't initialize MockitoAnnotations only once, in that way you risk that multiple tests are dependent on each other (or mocks are not initialized correctly). What happens if you remove `mockInitialized` and just call `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);` in your `setUp` method?

Comment: for @BeforeClass it needs to be static, that is supposed to be a workaround for that.
If I delete The mockInitialized it doesnt change anything.
I added the Errormessage to the Post.

Comment: try what's proposed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904584/mockito-gives-unfinishedverificationexception-when-it-seems-ok, at least it should give you the place where the error really is