# Exception when mocking Interface with Mockito

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am trying to test that an Interface method was called with and exact value passed in. I'm getting the following error:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException:  Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
>   -> at com.example.app.initialize(example.java:136)
>
> Example of correct verification:
>       verify(mock).doSomething()

The error is being thrown on this verification line:

`Mockito.verify(callback).onInitializeResult("initialized");`

My Interface class:

```
public interface InitCallback {
/**
 * Returns whether or not the app was initialized.     .
 */
    void onInitializeResult(String result);
}
```

My Unit Test:

```
@Test
    public void initializationTest(){
        InitCallback callback = Mockito.spy(new InitCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onInitializeResult(String result) {

            }
        });
        mExample.initialize(mContext, callback);
        Mockito.verify(callback).onInitializeResult("initialized");
    }
```

I also tried to replace the callback mock with:

```
InitCallback callback = Mockito.mock(InitCallback.class);
Mockito.doNothing().when(callback).onInitializeResult(Mockito.anyString());
```

However I still get the same error. The interface only has 1 method and it is not final. Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that mExample was calling another mocked instance whose methods were not defined. From another Stack Overflow post [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904584/mockito-gives-unfinishedverificationexception-when-it-seems-ok)

> Mockito throws exceptions if you misuse it so that you know if your
>   tests are written correctly. **The gotcha is that Mockito does the
>   validation next time you use the framework (e.g. next time you verify,
>   stub, call mock etc.)**. But even though the exception might be thrown
>   in the next test, the exception message contains a navigable stack
>   trace element with location of the defect. Hence you can click and
>   find the place where Mockito was misused.

So in the case posted in the question, The exception was generated in

```
mExample.initialize(mContext, callback);
```

but not thrown until the next time verify was called.