# UnfinishedVerificationException when verfying with Mockito.never()

Tags: java, mockito, spy

I have a Spring Boot Test with a Bean I want to spy on:

```
@SpyBean
private TimeseriesWriter writer;

@Test
public void testEmpty() {
    ...
    Mockito.verify(writer, Mockito.never()).updateTimeseries(any());
}
```

I was under the impression that this is how I verify that the updateTimeseries method is never called.
But I get following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedVerificationException: 
Missing method call for verify(mock) here:
-> at com.xxxTest.testEmpty(xxxTest.java:134)
```

Debugging shows that the method is definitely not called. So how do I verify that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31085466/6835152
Did u try updateTimeseries(anyInt());

Comment: yeah, that's it